# Rails Search form not working anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have implemented a simple search form in Rails 5, which looks for Locations by title. It worked, and I haven't touched the code since first implementing it. I've added several features since then (pagination, act as votable, tags), and for some reason the search form does not work. It appears the location title is being pulled in correctly:

/locations?utf8=✓&title=Brentwood

The issue is that all locations are being pulled in, as opposed to the ones being searched for.

Could there be something blocking this from working?

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode
acts_as_votable
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged


def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  new_record?
end

 def self.search(search)
 if search
  where("LOWER(search) LIKE ?", "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%")
 else
   all
 end
end


belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :image,
                styles: { large: "", medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#" },
                storage: :s3,
                :s3_protocol => :https,
                url: ":s3_domain_url",
                default_url: "placeholder.jpg",
                path: "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
                s3_region: ENV["S3_REGION"],
                s3_credentials: Proc.new { |a| a.instance.s3_credentials }




def s3_credentials
{
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
}
end



 acts_as_taggable



  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy



  end
```

Here is my locations_controller.rb file

```
   if params[:search]
   @locations = Location.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
   else
  @locations = Location.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
```

Here is my search form:

```
     <%= form_tag locations_path, method: :get do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Look for your spot!" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

I've tried multiple solutions that haven't worked yet.

Comment: What do you get in the result, all or no locations?

Comment: @archana sorry, I should've included that in the question. I receive all results.

Comment: Is param `search` permitted? Can you log the value in the controller and see what you receive?

Comment: @archana it's permitted

Comment: are you sending in params[:search]??

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer Are you referring to testing if search is permitted?

Comment: `if params[:search]` but your form has no `:search` field?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer gotcha. I just added :search param back into the form and receive the following error:  "Couldn't find Location with 'id'={:conditions=>["title LIKE ?", "%Example Location Title%"]}"

Answer (score 0):

**You are sending** `params[:title]` **While you are looking for** `params[:search]` **in your controller**

Either you change the `text_field_tag name attribute to search` OR change `Controller action to look for params[:title] instead of params[:search]`

Also please note, that you are searching with `LIKE` which is case sensitive. your search method should be adjust like the following line:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where("LOWER(title) LIKE ?", "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

OR if you are using PG you can use `ILIKE`

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where("title ILIKE ?", "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you @moustafa sallam. I've tried updating with both options, it still does not search for the title entered in the search field. I've also tried changing params[:title] to [:search] in my form, and that has not made a difference. Still pulls in all locations.

Comment: you did a mistake in the `location.rb` in the search method `where("LOWER(search) LIKE ?", "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%")` instead change it to `where("LOWER(title) LIKE ?", "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%")`

Comment: I'm sorry @moustafasallam but it still isn't pulling in my search results.

Comment: I am sorry too. These are the mistakes I can see from the code you showed.